# How do I write an SQL to get a cumulative value and a monthly total in one row?

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

Say, I have the following data:

```
  select 1 id, date '2007-01-16' date_created, 5 sales, 'Bob' name from dual union all
  select 2 id, date '2007-04-16' date_created, 2 sales, 'Bob' name from dual union all
  select 3 id, date '2007-05-16' date_created, 6 sales, 'Bob' name from dual union all
  select 4 id, date '2007-05-21' date_created, 4 sales, 'Bob' name from dual union all
  select 5 id, date '2013-07-16' date_created, 24 sales, 'Bob' name from dual union all
  select 6 id, date '2007-01-17' date_created, 15 sales, 'Ann' name from dual union all
  select 7 id, date '2007-04-17' date_created, 12 sales, 'Ann' name from dual union all
  select 8 id, date '2007-05-17' date_created, 16 sales, 'Ann' name from dual union all
  select 9 id, date '2007-05-22' date_created, 14 sales, 'Ann' name from dual union all
  select 10 id, date '2013-07-17' date_created, 34 sales, 'Ann' name from dual
```

I want to get results like the following:

```
Name        Total_cumulative_sales      Total_sales_current_month
Bob         41                          24
Ann         91                          34
```

In this table, for Bob, his total sales is 41 starting from the beginning. And for this month which is July, his sales for this entire month is 24. Same goes for Ann.

How do I write an SQL to get this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select name, sum(sales) as Total_cumulative_sales ,
       sum( 
            case trunc(to_date(date_created), 'MM')
              when  trunc(sysdate, 'MM') then sales
              else 0
            end
        ) as  Total_sales_current_month

from tab
group by name
```

### **SQL Fiddle** [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f455/24/0)

---

More information

- [Trunc](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)
- [Case Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)

Comment: I think this adds sales from the same month but over different years. Is this what is wanted?

Comment: @Darkzaelus [See this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92865/1/0) I've changed first row to `2007-07-16` and it still works

Comment: Then I retract, apologies :) I'll have to read up on the `trunc` function to figure out how that works

Comment: Ooooh it doesn't just bring back the month, it returns it with the day and any other less relevant data basically rounded down. Clever

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(Sales) Total_sales, 
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(GetDate()) AND YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(GetDate()) THEN Sales END) Total_sales_current_month
GROUP BY Name
```

Should work, but there's probably a more elegant way to specify "in the current month".

Answer (score 2):

This should work for sales over a number of years. It will get the cumulative sales over any number of years. It won't produce a record if there are no sales in the latest month.

```
    WITH sales AS 
(select 1 id, date '2007-01-16' date_created, 5 sales, 'Bob' sales_name from dual union all
  select 2 id, date '2007-04-16' date_created, 2 sales, 'Bob' sales_name from dual union all
  select 3 id, date '2007-05-16' date_created, 6 sales, 'Bob' sales_name from dual union all
  select 4 id, date '2007-05-21' date_created, 4 sales, 'Bob' sales_name from dual union all
  select 5 id, date '2013-07-16' date_created, 24 sales, 'Bob' sales_name from dual union all
  select 6 id, date '2007-01-17' date_created, 15 sales, 'Ann' sales_name from dual union all
  select 7 id, date '2007-04-17' date_created, 12 sales, 'Ann' sales_name from dual union all
  select 8 id, date '2007-05-17' date_created, 16 sales, 'Ann' sales_name from dual union all
  select 9 id, date '2007-05-22' date_created, 14 sales, 'Ann' sales_name from dual union all
  select 10 id, date '2013-07-17' date_created, 34 sales, 'Ann' sales_name from dual)
  SELECT  sales_name
         ,total_sales
         ,monthly_sales
         ,mon 
  FROM (SELECT sales_name
              ,SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_name ORDER BY mon) total_sales
              ,SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_name,mon ORDER BY mon) monthly_sales
              ,mon 
              ,max_mon
        FROM (  SELECT sales_name
                      ,sum(sales) sales
                      ,mon
                      ,max_mon
                FROM   (SELECT sales_name
                              ,to_number(to_char(date_created,'YYYYMM')) mon
                              ,sales
                              ,MAX(to_number(to_char(date_created,'YYYYMM'))) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_name) max_mon
                        FROM sales
                        ORDER BY 2)
                GROUP BY sales_name
                        ,max_mon
                        ,mon
             )
        )
WHERE max_mon = mon
```

;